# Gatsby transforming string into relative path

Tags: gatsby, netlify-cms, jamstack

I have a field in the frontmatter for a page `my_field: /contact/`. When I query this field on my page it gets transformed into `../pages/contact` but I want it to be exactly what I typed, just `/contact/`.

How do I prevent Gatsby from transforming my string field into a relative path?

edit: I do have a page that comes from '/pages/contact.js' My custom field comes from a configurable nav that is trying to link to that page. I want to pass /contact/ in the Gatsby Link to param. But typing /contact/ into the field comes through as ../pages/contact.

Comment: Is it that you have a file called `contact.js`? And, if so, where is located? If your site is up and running at `localhost:8000` and you try to go to `localhost:8000/contact`, you'll need to have a file called `contact.js` in `src/pages`. Gatsby takes care of this routing automatically. Or, have I misunderstood your situation?

Comment: Do you have any code to look at?